# How to assign textbox.text to selected dropdownlist value?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a page where the user selects a product. I wish to then populate the textbox value with the selected ddl value to allow them to update the value if necessary. My ddl is being populated properly.

When I debug this, the textbox uxProductFamilyUpvalue appears to be assigned the ddlProductFamilies.SelectedValue but when I return to the page, the textbox is null.

Any ideas?
TY

```
Imports ThomasOE.Globals
Imports ThomasOE.Utilities
Imports ThomasOE.Product
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls

Public Class frmProducts
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load                
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            FillProductTypesDropdown()
            DisplayLoginDetails(Master, Session.Item(SSNLOGINNAME), Session.Item(SSNCURRENTDATETIME))
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub FillProductTypesDropdown()
        Dim objProduct As New Product

        Try

            objProduct.FillProductTypeDS()

            ddlProductTypes.Items.Clear()
            ddlProductTypes.Items.Add(String.Empty)

            For i As Integer = 0 To objProduct.ProductTypeDS.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                ddlProductTypes.Items.Add(objProduct.ProductTypeDS.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("product_type"))
            Next

            objProduct = Nothing

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub FillProductFamiliesDropdown()

        Dim objProduct As New Product

        Try

            objProduct.FillProductFamilyDS(ddlProductTypes.Text)

            ddlProductFamilies.Items.Clear()
            ddlProductFamilies.Items.Add(String.Empty)

            For i As Integer = 0 To objProduct.ProductFamilyDS.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                ddlProductFamilies.Items.Add(objProduct.ProductFamilyDS.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("product_family"))               
            Next

            objProduct = Nothing

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try


    End Sub

    Protected Sub ddlProductTypes_SelectedIndexChanged1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlProductTypes.SelectedIndexChanged
        FillProductFamiliesDropdown()

    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateProductPage()        
        uxProductTypeUp.Text = ddlProductTypes.SelectedValue
        uxProductFamilyUp.Text = ddlProductFamilies.SelectedItem.Text

    End Sub

    Protected Sub ddlProductFamilies_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlProductFamilies.SelectedIndexChanged
        'UpdateProductPage()            
        uxProductFamilyUp.Text = ddlProductFamilies.SelectedItem.Text

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Is the dropdownlist also empty when you return to page?

Comment: No. That has the proper selected item. I was able to assign a static value to the textbox on page_load...but

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the fact that you have already loaded the page.
In the way to change values in DDL you can use AJAX call with jQuery.

Include jQuery in site master header

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

On the aspx page where you have your DDL add something like

```
    //DropDownList1 on change AJAX
    $("#<%=DropdownList1.ClientID %>").change(function () {
        GetData();
    });

   function GetData() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            //here you have to call vb.net function
            url: "Default.aspx/GetDataVB",
            data: '{ddl_val: "' + $("#<%=DropDownList1.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: GetData_OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
    });
    }
    function GetData_OnSuccess(response) {
        $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").html(response.d);
    }
```

into vb code

```
 <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
 Public Shared Function GetDataVB(ByVal ddl_val As String) As String

     return ddl_val

 end function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an `OnItemSelected` event to the dropdownlist and set the text of the TextBox in the event definition in the code behind